# how to do put request using node.js and add the json file

Tags: node.js

Hi I am new to this domain, I am trying to do PUT request and add the json file. I have the json file created and i have to perform put and post request using the URI's please can any one post a code using nodejs and it will be helpful.I created a put request file like this

```
var i = 0;
var fs = require("fs");
var request = require('request');
var jsonPath =     fs.readFileSync('filepath');
// String --> Object
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonPath);
console.log(changedevicename.call());
for( i = 0; i < jsonObj.ipConfig.length; i++) 
{
   var ipv4URI = jsonObj.ipConfig[i].ipv4;                                           // taking ipv4 json file
   var ipv6URI = jsonObj.ipConfig[i].ipv6;                                       // taking ipv6 json file
   console.log(ipv4URI);
   console.log(ipv6URI);

   rest_service();
   //console.log(config[i]);
}

function rest_service()                                                        // should I change this or what  
{
    var i = 0;
    var request = require('request');

    var options =   {
       url: 'http://'+'USERNAME'+':'+'PASSWORD'+ '@'+'IPV6'+'URI',              
       method: 'PUT',
    } 
{
    //IP = userGivenIP;
    //IP = '192.168.0.1';        

       request( 
              {
               method:'PUT',
               url: 'http://'+'USERNAME'+':'+'PASSWORD'+ '@'+'IPV6'+'URI',            // 
               headers: {
                         'Content-Type': 'application/json',                       // check this, I should change this
                        },
                        //var ip4Json = JSON.parse(body);                        // check this, I should change this
                        //console.log('\n\n'+ body + '\n\n');
          },     
               function (error, response, body)                        // check this, I should change this
         {
              if (error!=undefined)
              {
              console.log(body);
              }
              else
              {
              console.log("printerror", error);
              console.log("IP disabled");
              }


         });
}


This code has to be doen dynamically but I am not getting how to do this for put and post request please help me out and mail the code thanks.
```

thanks and regards
Prathamesh

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `body` parameter to request.

```
const jsonBody = {
    key1: value1,
    key2: value2
};

const headers = {
    authorization: "<token>"
};

const options = {
        method: 'PUT',
        uri: "some-url",
        headers: headers,   // headers if your api requires
        body: jsonBody,
        json: true
};

request(options, function(err, response) {
     // handle err first
     // do  stuff with response
});
```

You should go through the docs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/request